# What to add to this Hello World code in C?

Tags: c, char, int, void

I am very new to programming with C and I can't find a way to add to this program in order to spell `"Hello, World!"` without deleting any lines of code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void modify_1(char *c);
void modify_2(char *c);

int main()
{
    char str1[10];
    char str2[15];
    printf("%s, %s!\n", str1, str2);
}

void modify_1(char *c)
{
    char *a_string = "hello";
}

void modify_2(char *c)
{
    char *a_string = "world";
}
```

Comment: The function isn't return anything. Also doesn't process the arguments. Where do you call those functions? what is the reference of *c?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code (see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SyFvauhvS) in onlineGDB):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void modify_1(char *c);
void modify_2(char *c);

int main(void)
{
    char str1[10];
    char str2[15];

    modify_1(str1);
    modify_2(str2);
    printf("%s, %s!\n", str1, str2);
}

void modify_1(char *c)
{
    strcpy(c, "hello");
}

void modify_2(char *c)
{
    strcpy(c, "world");
}
```

There are a few changes:

1. You actually call `modify_1` and `modify_2` (otherwise, why would they affect anything?)
2. Within the functions, you use [`strcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) to copy the content of the literal to the address.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find a way to add to this program in order to spell `"Hello, World!"`
>   without deleting any lines of code here.

Given that you cannot delete any lines, you need only ***add*** 2-lines of code to each of your `modify_1` and `modify_2` functions to (1) copy the *string-literals* to your array, and then (2) change the first characters from lowercase to uppercase, and then just call `modify_1` and `modify_2` before you print. 
For example:

```
void modify_1 (char *c)
{
    char *a_string = "hello";
    strcpy (c, a_string);         /* copy a_string to your array */
    c[0] = c[0] + 'A' - 'a';      /* change 1st character to uppercase */
}

void modify_2 (char *c)
{
    char *a_string = "world";
    strcpy (c, a_string);         /* same thing */
    c[0] = c[0] + 'A' - 'a';
}
```

After making the changes, you simply call the functions before your print statement in `main()`, e.g.

```
int main()
{
    char str1[10];
    char str2[15];

    modify_1 (str1);
    modify_2 (str2);

    printf("%s, %s!\n", str1, str2);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/modify_12
Hello, World!
```

See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) to understand how the conversion from lowercase to uppercase takes place.

Comment: @M.M - Thank you. I was on auto-pilot and didn't even pick up those additions `:)`  (bet that was confusing....magic!)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what is intended by the person that gave you the assignment but the simplest solution is to add two lines in `main` and leave the rest unchanged (and unused :-)

```
int main()
{
    char str1[10];
    char str2[15];
    strcpy(str1, "Hello");  // Add this line
    strcpy(str2, "World");  // Add this line
    printf("%s, %s!\n", str1, str2);
}
```